# NodeJS Forge viewer ErrorCode:9. No viewable content

Tags: autodesk-forge

Having followed the *View BIM 360 & Fusion models* tutorial @ http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels, I'm running into trouble when trying to load a test Revit model on my A360 account...

I recive the error `ErrorCode:9. No viewable content`, is this because I haven't translated my source Revit file using the Model Derivative API?

Comment: It report the error of "No Viewable content", can you open the origin file in Revit and check if any views are exported from "Publish Settings"? You can get the setting by "Collabrate" tab -> "Publish Settings".

Comment: That's actually the first thing I checked. I've exported dozens of 3D views in this model.

Comment: It might be worth noting that all the Demo project files also respond with the same ErrorCode:9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Demo` project from BIM 360 Team (formerly A360) are tricky to work with, they are just sallow copies... can you try upload your own model and translate? Here are a few [Revit sample](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html) models.